# Show that $ PH^T(HPH^T + N)^{-1} = (P^{-1} + H^TN^{-1}H)^{-1}H^TN^{-1} $

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Show that: $$ PH^T(N + HPH^T)^{-1} = (P^{-1} + H^TN^{-1}H)^{-1}H^TN^{-1} $$

Given: P and N are symmetric matrices. All matrices are square matrices in the same size.

I tried using [Woodbury Matrix Identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity), which is

$$\left(A+UCV \right)^{-1} = A^{-1} - A^{-1}U \left(C^{-1}+VA^{-1}U \right)^{-1} VA^{-1}.$$

My equation became

$$ PH^T \left[ N^{-1} - N^{-1}H\underbrace{(P^{-1} + H^TN^{-1}H)^{-1}H^TN^{-1}}_{K} \right] = \underbrace{(P^{-1} + H^TN^{-1}H)^{-1}H^TN^{-1}}_{K} $$

$$ PH^T \left[ N^{-1} - N^{-1}HK \right] = K $$

$$ PH^TN^{-1} - PH^TN^{-1}HK = K $$

$$ PH^TN^{-1} = K + PH^TN^{-1}HK. $$

I'm stuck at this point. I'm not able to go any further. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Write your identity as
$(P^{-1} + H^TN^{-1}H)PH^T = H^TN^{-1}(N + HPH^T)$.